# How do I fix the problem of my device manager not opening any of my emulators

Tags: android, emulation

I just upgraded my Android studios after a 2 year hiatus to Hedgehog. I set up an AVD but now I cannot even run the sample code that comes with the download.

When I run flutter doctor I get this:

[image]

My android SDK path shows to be this:

```
C:\Users\ttuck\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
```

When I try to select a device from the device selector i get this error pop up:

```
INFO | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A)
INFO | Found systemPath C:\Users\ttuck\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-33\google_apis_playstore\x86_64\
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 5818:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0 (2x)
ERROR | Running multiple emulators with the same AVD
ERROR | is an experimental feature.
ERROR | Please use -read-only flag to enable this feature.
INFO | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 3256
INFO | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
INFO | IPv4 server found:
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 60f8:43ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 60f8:43ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 38fe:43ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 38fe:43ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 5004:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 5004:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 3812:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 3812:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0 (2x)
INFO | Ignore IPv6 address: 5818:44ed:802:0:60f8:43ed:802:0
```

I was expecting for the sample code to open with the counter app. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using flutter config like it recommends?

Comment: I ran this code from the cmd terminal: C:\Users\ttuck>flutter config --android-sdk 'C:\Users\ttuck\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk'....... i got no change when i restarted android Studios. i received the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I went to the SDK platform and platform-tools folder within my Android SDK folder and added them to the Path section of the System Variables on my computer. I added the following to my Path folder:

```
C:\Users\ttuck\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform
C:\Users\ttuck\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

Once I restarted the Android Studios App I was able to open the emulator. I have other gradle problems now but my problem is fixed now.